# div overlap - fluid / bootstrap

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I am making some style adjustments to this site
http://neondataskills.org/

I have added a top bar image and now, when you resize the page, the top bar graphic, overlaps the navigation if it gets too wide. I'd like to force the image to push the navigation bar down.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="navigation-wrapper">
<div class="NEON-header">
<img src="/images/banners/header_whole.png" alt="NEON" style="width:100%;">
</div>
    <div class="site-name">
        <a href="{{ site.url }}">{{ site.title }}</a>
    </div><!-- /.site-name -->
    <div class="top-navigation">
        <nav role="navigation" id="site-nav" class="nav">
            <ul>
                {% for link in site.links %}
                <li><a href="{% if link.external %}{{ link.url }}{% else %}{{ site.url }}{{ link.url }}{% endif %}" {% if link.external %}target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ link.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /.top-navigation -->
</div><!-- /.navigation-wrapper -->
```

Currently, the site name and top-navigation divs are "covered" by the NEON-header div when you make the page wider.  I found some code in stack that suggests i need to use the "after" element in my css however that doesn't seem to work either.

CSS:

```
.NEON-header {
    background-color: #1ea0c1;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10em;
    padding: 0;
}

/* this could potentially force the div to clear but it doesn't */
.NEON-header:before, .NEON-header:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: ""
}
.NEON-header:after {
    clear: both;
}

.navigation-wrapper::before, .navigation-wrapper::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}
.navigation-wrapper::after {
    clear:both;
}

.site-name {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-left: 4.16667%;
    margin-right: 4.16667%;
    padding: 1em 0 0;
    width: 16.6667%;
}

.top-navigation {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 1em 0 0;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Any ideas what else i can try to force the div's to stack above and below each other rather than having the top div overlapping into the nav bar?
Many thanks for any ideas
leah

Comment: what top nav divs are overlapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `.NEON-header` has `0px` height and your image size is growing. Just remove the `height: 0;` from your `.NEON-header`. Example:

```
.NEON-header {
  background-color: #1ea0c1;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! i'd up vote this but i don't have enough reputation points yet. this fixed it. i don't know how i missed it - been staring at the css for while.